# Switch order of item in Observable Collection - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Say I have 3 items in my observable collection and I want to swap the "indexes" of item1 (index of 1) and item2 (index of 2) so that item1 has an index of 2 and item2 has an index of 1. How easy is this to do? In needs to also be reflected in the UI where my ListView's itemsource is bound to the observable collection.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` has a `MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)` function. Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.moveitem?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @uaswpf please accept this answer as the solution if your problem is solved